# Configurable Product - Get child product id

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

How to get child product id's from parent product id in magento2 for configurable product?

I want to get child product id of parent product in magento based on parent product id.

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the below solution:

```
<?php
    $productId = 5; //Configurable product ID
    $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $_product = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
    $_childProducts = $_product->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($_product);
    foreach ($_childProducts as $simpleProduct){
        echo $simpleProduct->getId();
    }
?>
```

***Suggestion:*** Don't use object manager directly in your code as its not a best practice. You need to inject the product model class to your respective class then use it.

Comment: yes i have injected model and working fine. Thanks @sukumar

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$configProduct = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$_children = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getUsedProducts($configProduct);

foreach ($_children as $child){
    echo $child->getID();
}
```